# Laravel 7 Vue getting favorite button

Tags: laravel, vue.js

is there something wrong with this part? getting this on console

> app.js:38308 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you
> register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure
> to provide the "name" option.
>
> (found in )

here is the code

```
<template>
    <span>
        <a href="#" v-if="isFavorited" @click.prevent="unFavorite(post)">
            <i  class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" v-else @click.prevent="favorite(post)">
            <i  class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
        </a>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['post', 'favorited'],

        data: function() {
            return {
                isFavorited: '',
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.isFavorited = this.isFavorite ? true : false;
        },

        computed: {
            isFavorite() {
                return this.favorited;
            },
        },

        methods: {
            favorite(post) {
                axios.post('/favorite/'+post)
                    .then(response => this.isFavorited = true)
                    .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
            },

            unFavorite(post) {
                axios.post('/unfavorite/'+post)
                    .then(response => this.isFavorited = false)
                    .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like you've posted the component that causes the error - post the code that is using this component

Comment: well you use it in your views by placeing <favorited> tag the issue was it wasnt displaying the button